# Any way to download swf files on android?

Tags: downloading, adobe-flash

I want to download an swf file on my phone. I have the link of the swf, but nothing worked, chrome just ignores the link while other browsers(dolphin in this case) run the swf file and still no download option. I cannot play it in dolphin because it always crashes at a specific part. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download the page it's on as HTML, find the link to the file, and then use ES's Download Manager to download it. But that's just me.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to download it with your link, you can use Advanced download manager or similar applications.